# Create list object from "_ElementUnicodeResult object of lxml.etree module"

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm new to Python and hope to scrape real estate data from a listings website. I've succeeded in pulling text from the page, but the returned object is not what I expected.

```
# import modules
from lxml import html
import requests

# specify webpage to scrape
url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/Result/e1fdabc8-9b53-470f-9728-b6ab1a5d1204/1'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# scrape desired information
address_raw = tree.xpath('//a[@class="search-nav-link"]//text()')
price_raw = tree.xpath('//span[@class="font-weight-bold listing-price d-block pull-left pr-25"]//text()')
```

As expected, the objects `address_raw` and `price_raw` are lists. But the values contained within this list are not strings with the obtained addresses and prices immediately visible. Instead, they all say `[_ElementUnicodeResult object of lxml.etree module]`. Typing the object name (e.g., `address_raw`) into the interpreter shows the addresses in the list, as does `print(address_raw)`. How can I create a simple list of addresses and prices as strings, without the list values showing up as `[_ElementUnicodeResult object of lxml.etree module]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str()` to cast an object to a string and `map()` to apply the function to each element of the list:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/Result/e1fdabc8-9b53-470f-9728-b6ab1a5d1204/1'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

address_raw = list(map(str, tree.xpath('//a[@class="search-nav-link"]//text()')))
price_raw = list(map(str, tree.xpath('//span[@class="font-weight-bold listing-price d-block pull-left pr-25"]//text()')))
print(type(address_raw[0])) # => <class 'str'>
print(type(price_raw[0]))   # => <class 'str'>
```